# How to find change points in a graph on matlab

Tags: statistics, graphing-functions, matlab

I have a graph like this[image]

I need to find points at which sudden changes happening for the DPC Time Curve.
We can observe that at time 20 and around 70 increase is happening. How to do this in Matlab. Is there any method or predefined functions available to find this change points? How to do this mathematically?

Comment: This isn't an easy problem, but you might try starting with the `findpeaks` function. Another option might be `houghpeaks`, which has a couple of companion functions that go along with it. Both are very well documented.